# Where can I find etter.dns of ettercap-graphical for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: networking, 16.04, apt, dns

I did reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and try to install  ettercap-graphical.
Everything is going right until I try to consult the dns of ettercap.
Normally the `etter.dns`  is in the `/usr/share/ettercap` directory and that's what I did find:

[image]

Did `etter.dns` has another name or other location, or did I install it the wrong way?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ettercap-graphical
```